# How to use select2 inputs as json decoded values and loop through them in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, codeigniter

Hi am trying to use select2 multi-select and sending the selected options via ajax to PHP codeigniter controller. I need to loop through the json decoded values in the model, but it is not working.

**Javascript used to post the selected values :**

```
$("#add_group").on("click",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var $group=document.getElementById('group').value;
        var $foreman=$("#foreman").select2("data");
        var $foreman_id=$foreman['id'];
        var $foreman_name=$foreman['text'];
        var $employee = $("#employee").select2("data");

        var employees = {
            info: []
        };

        var keys = Object.keys($employee),
            len = keys.length,
            i = 0,
            prop,
            value;
        while (i < len) {
            prop = keys[i];
            value = $employee[prop];
            employees.info.push({
                "id" : value.id,
                "name"  : value.text

            });
            i += 1;
            console.log('Employees : '+employees.info)
        }
        var $json_emp= JSON.stringify(employees);
        console.log('Employees : '+$json_emp);
        ajax("add_group",$group,$foreman_id,$foreman_name,$json_emp);
    });
```

**Model:**

```
public function add_group()
   {
       $group = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('group'));
       $foreman_id = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('foreman_id'));
       $foreman_name = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('foreman_name'));
       $json_emp = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('json_emp'));

       $array_emp = json_decode($json_emp,true);
       var_dump($array_emp);
       //echo json_encode($array_emp);
       //return false;
        print_r($array_emp->info);
       $emp_ids = '';
       $emp_names='';
       $i=0;
       //$employee_id = $array_emp['info'][$i]['id'];
       //$employee_name = $array_emp['info'][$i]['name'];


               foreach( $array_emp['info'][$i] as $emp_info){
                   $emp_ids.=$emp_info->id;
                   $emp_names.=$emp_info->name;
                   $i=$i+1;
               }



       echo 'Employee IDs'.$emp_ids;
       $crt_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
       $data_group = array(
           'group_name'      => $group,
           'foreman_id'      => $foreman_id,
           'foreman_name'    => $foreman_name,
           'employees_in_group'      => $emp_names,
           'employees_in_group_id'   => $emp_ids,
           'rec_status'     => 'A',
           'crt_dt'         => $crt_date,

       );
       $result = $this->db->insert('group', $data_group);
       $insert_id=$this->db->insert_id();
       if($insert_id)
           return $insert_id;
       else
           return false;
   }
```

**Print_r Output of the json_decode()**

```
Array
(
    [info] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 10
                    [name] => employee1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 12
                    [name] => emplyee3
                )

        )

)
```

**var_dump output of the array**

```
array(1) {
  ["info"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(2) "10"
      ["name"]=>
      string(9) "employee1"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(2) "11"
      ["name"]=>
      string(9) "employee2"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(2) "12"
      ["name"]=>
      string(8) "emplyee3"
    }
  }
}
```

> **How can I loop through these values in the model ?**

**Tried but failed codes are below  :**

```
$emp_ids = '';
       $emp_names='';
       $i=0;
       foreach($array_emp as $row) { //foreach element in $arr
           foreach($row['info'] as $employees){
               foreach($employees[$i] as $emp_info){
                   $emp_ids.=$emp_info['id'];
                   $emp_names.=$emp_info['name'];
               }
           }
           $i=$i+1;
       }
```

Comment: select2 uses a hidden dropdown menu to store the data, And you should only use ids not the entire data (relying on user input to get values is a big mistake), normally I wouldn't loop through anything a simple ```$form.serialize()``` should be good enough to receive the form data on the other end.

Comment: I was using $form.serialize() for the forms, but can we access the select2 data using the same ?

Comment: You don't need select2 data, you only need the dropdown values which is in the dropdown that select2 hide when it's initialized so you'll be receiving ids only without names when using $form.serialize(), then you'll have to process the ids to get names if you really need to (which means you're using a validated input instead of relying on user input).

Comment: when using $form.seralize(), you should receive something like this in PHP ``$employees_ids = array(0 => 10, 1 => 11, 2 => 12)`` then you can use a query to validate & get names ``$this->db->where_in('id', $employees_ids)->get('employees');``